# How to automate clicking a specific button repeatedly with AppleScript?

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to write a script that will:

- Open a particular program
- Click on a button at a particular spot within the program window
- Repeat the click a certain number of times with a specified delay between clicks

I'm planning to use iCal to schedule running the script, but what should the actual script look like? Could it be run on the background without making any windows visible?

Answer (score 0):

Most native applications support UI scripting like this:

```
reopen application "Finder" -- open a default window if there are no open windows
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Finder"
    repeat 3 times
        click button 2 of window 1
        delay 1
    end repeat
end tell
```

If you get an error like "Access for assistive devices is disabled", enable access for assistive devices from the accessibility preference pane.

If you have Xcode, you can use Accessibility Inspector to inspect UI elements. Or use something like this:

```
reopen application "Finder"
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Finder" to tell window 1
    {class, value} of UI elements of UI elements
    description of UI elements
    properties of some UI element
    attributes of some UI element
    value of attribute "AXFocused" of some UI element
    actions of button 2
end tell
```

If `click` doesn't work, try `perform action "AXPress"`, `set selected to true`, or `set focused to true`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Because of my limited (almost nonexistent) programming ability, I need a little more help.<p>Because I don't have xcode, I'm not able to identify the UI elements (unless there's an easy way to do it that I'm not aware of). I tried using "click at" with the coordinates of the button location but can't get it to work. Perhaps I'm formatting it incorrectly. (e.g. click at {70, 808})

Comment: You can also record actions in Automator and then copy and paste them to AppleScript Editor. `tell application "System Events" to tell process "Application" to click at {70, 808}` should normally work.